# Вложенная условная тернарная операция

Tags: c++, условия, тернарный-оператор

```
int main()
{
    const char x[2][20] = { "ab ", " ba" };
    const char* y = "c";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        cout << ((i<2)? !i ? x[i] : y : x[1]);
    
}
```

Вывод: **ab c ba**

Объясните, что происходит в cout после варажения1. Что делает **операция (не)** с 0 и 1? Почему второй элемент массива под индексом 1 выводиться в конце?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возьмём это выражение `((i<2)? !i ? x[i] : y : x[1]);`, отломаем ручки тому, кто его написал и чуточку перепишем.

```
((i<2)? (!i ? x[i] : y)  : x[1])
```

Теперь стало понятно, кто кому.

само выражение !i - просто дает true, если i == 0 и наоборот. Переписываем

```
((i<2)? ( (i == 0) ? x[i] : y)  : x[1])
```

разворачиваем:

```
if (i < 2) {
   cout << (i == 0) ? x[i] : y;
} else {
   cout << x[1];
}
```

ну а теперь уже все понятно

```
0 -> x[i]
1 -> y
2 -> x[1]
```